# HTML. Формы. Как зафиксировать часть значения в текстовом поле формы?

Tags: html, forms

Как зафиксировать часть значения в поле формы, оставив пользователю возможность лишь добавить свою часть, не стирая предустановленное значение?

Допустим, в поле я указываю телефонный код государства, а пользователь должен лишь дополнить его, не имея возможности стереть.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так можно

```js
var prefix = '375-'
var inputVal;

$('#prefix').val(prefix);

$('#prefix').on('keyup change', function(){
  inputVal = $(this).val();
  if(inputVal.substr(0, prefix.length) != prefix){
    $(this).val(prefix + inputVal.substr(prefix.length-1))
  }
  console.log(inputVal.substr(0, prefix.length));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="prefix" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, вашу идею понял!
Правда хотелось еще сделать так чтобы в код нельзя было даже поставить курсор.

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать псевдокласс, в котором введешь тел. код государства (а также тугглить его посредством js при нужном изменении), а в самом текстовом поле подвинуть область ввода правее. Заместо освободившегося пространства подвинуть с использованием позиционирования псевдокласс. И никакого js для такой статики не нужно. 
Та же самая реализация используется, если нужно картиночку (значок телефона) в текстовое поле поместить для стилизации, это делается простым позиционированием и псевдоклассом. Просто для стилизации информации, вводимой в форме, ты наверняка же где-то такое встречал.

В любой ситуации рекомендую не использовать js, если возможна реализация при помощи css.

Comment: Пока не знаю что такое псевдокласс, но принцип ясен, будем изучать.
Спасибо.

Comment: @ВиталийКомаров, тогда понятно, почему ты о нем сразу же не подумал) Изучи, это не долго.